# Selected all child elements to hide, but wont unhide all elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am making a jquery accordion following css-tricks tut [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/). I modified the code a bit and I selected all the elements within the parent element and hid it. Upon click it will reveal the `dd` tags, but not the `ul` or `h3` tag. I feel like it has to do with the code on line 6 or 7 of the JS section but I don't understand JS/jQuery well enough to know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/undeE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` only selects the next sibling of the selected element, you can use `nextUntil` method instead.

```
var $target = $this.parent().nextUntil('dt');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bDdCH/

However, if you wrap the target elements by another element (like a div element) then `next` will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the help and information! I cant wrap the elements within another because the content will not be static. I will accept your answer after the time limit.